# Faster RCNN is not able to recognize composed elements

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, faster-rcnn

I tried to [fine tune Faster RCNN](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) to realize object detection task with bounding boxes where I shall recognize face, eyes and mouth on image. However Faster RCNN seems to fail to recognize objects when they contain another one(face contains nose). I tried the same task on faces only and it worked good.

Is it a general behavior? How can I explain that? Is there a trick to get over it?

Comment: what do you get when face contains nose, for example?

Comment: either no box for face or a completely wrong prediction for face